# set value in javascript class

Tags: javascript, class

i wrote i a class for practicing, can anyone tell me why it print 2 instead of 1?

```
function hnclass(){
    var h=1;
    function print(){
        console.info(h); //here it print 1
    }
    return {
        item:h,
        printout:print
    }
}

hc=new hnclass();
hc.item=2;
hc.printout();
console.log(hc.item); //here it print 2
```

with `hc.item=2;` i am changing value of `item`, so after that, when i am calling the print function it should print out `2`. i was thinking is it possible without a setter function set value in this kind of class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can anyone tell me why it print 2 instead of 1

Because setting the value of a variable or property **never** changes the value of another variable or property. Here is a simplified example:

```
var a = 1;
var b = a;
a = 42;
```

Assigning a new value to `a` doesn't change the value of `b`, even though `b` had the same value as `a` originally.
In your case, assigning a value to `hc.item` simply doesn't change the value of `h`.

> i was thinking is it possible without a setter function set value in this kind of class?

Yes, if you also access `x.item` inside `print`:

```
function hnclass(){
    var h=1;
    function print(){
        console.info(obj.item);
    }
    var obj = {
        item:h,
        printout:print
    };
    return obj;
}
```

---

However, this whole setup doesn't really have anything to do with OOP or classes. Maybe [Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) helps you to get a better understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't write a class, you wrote a function.  Here are you mistakes, explicitly.

1. You didn't scope your variables to the class by using `this` and instead they are private variables.
2. You added a return statement that overrode your class definition.  If you add

   console.info(hc  instanceof hnclass);

you'll see that your variable `hc` is NOT an instance of your class.

Here is the corrected code.

```
function hnclass () {
    var self = this;
    this.item = 1; 
    this.printout = function print () {
        console.info(this.item); 
    }
}
var hc = new hnclass();
hc.printout(); // will display 1
hc.item = 4;

console.info(hc  instanceof hnclass); // will display true
hc.printout(); // will display 4
console.log(hc.item); // will display 4
```

I suggest you study more on closures, scoping, how functions differ from classes, and how to test if a variable belongs to a class with instanceof.

Answer (score 0):

In your 'class' declaration, the `h` is a local variable. If you want to create a attribute, you have to do something like :

```
function hnclass () {
    this.item = 1; // Here item is a attribute of your class
    this.printout = function print () {
        console.info(this.item); // Use this.item instead of h
    }
}
hn = new hnclass () ;
hn.printout() ;
hn.item = 4 ;
hn.printout() ;
```

This is a very simple example, you can use `prototype` to have a more organized code.